# Using a handwriting font from myscriptfont.com

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'd like to use a font created from my handwriting at myscriptfont.com. It generates either OTF or TTF fonts, and they are usable (obviously with many limitations!) in various OS X programs.

I can't get them to work under XeLaTeX, however. Here's my minimal example (you'll need either my [ScottMorrison.otf](http://tqft.net/misc/ScottMorrison.otf) or [ScottMorrison.ttf](http://tqft.net/misc/ScottMorrison.ttf) font installed).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setmainfont{ScottMorrison}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

which produces the message

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ScottMorrison(0)/m/n' undefined
>   (Font)              using`T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.

and, of course, text in Computer Modern.

(Note that it really is seeing the installed font file, if you change the `\setmainfont` command to some other string completely different error messages arise.)

> Is there some way to make fonts like these usable in XeLaTeX?

Comment: Don't use the `fontenc` package; the `fontspec` package uses the `EU1` encoding and sets that automatically.

Comment: @ScottMorrison Don't load `xltxtra`, but simply `fontspec`. It used to be recommended to load `xltxtra`, not any more nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `fontenc` package; the `fontspec` package uses its own encodings (`EU1` in XeTeX and `EU2` in LuaTeX) and sets them automatically.